# Condition variables and Locks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, operating-system, locking

Specifically thinking about Java, Let say I have lock object

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition cond = aLock.newCondition();

public void a(){
  lock.lock();
  while(available == false){
    //available is some boolean from somewhere
    cond.await();
  } 
  cond.signal();
  lock.unlock();
}
```

I don't understand how this works. If I am calling `cond.await()` while being inside `void a()`, then also calling `cond.signal()` inside the same `void a()` how will I ever get notified in `void a()`? I mean to say if `signal` is after the loop, how will I ever break from the loop. It seems like an infinite situation.

I copied this code from somewhere so that's why I am asking. Thanks

Comment: some other method may invoke cond.singal() to get a() out of cond.await() and when available is true, a() can signal some other method out of await().

Comment: Did you read the [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) docs?

Comment: @user1803551, yes but I was confused which is why I asked here

Comment: But it shows exactly how it works: `cond.singal()` is called from somewhere else.

Comment: @user1803551, yes I saw that, but I got confused due to another example which has `signal` within the same function.